# Replace numeric interval with text interval

Tags: php, laravel, text, intervals

I've been editing and cleaning up the code on an accounting app for a company I work with. When users sign up they tell us how often to check their accounts for new information. At the moment, it uses a numeric dropdown list of 1 to 30 days based upon the date they signed up. The code is below.

```
<div class="{{ $class }}">
                        <label for="syst_interval">How often do you want us to scan your account?</label>

                        <?php $value = ($user->syst_settings->syst_interval) ?: Input::old('syst_interval'); ?>
                        <select name="syst_interval" id="syst_interval" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0">Select value</option>
                            @for( $i=0; $i<30; $i++ )
                                <?php if( $value == ($i+1) ) $selected = 'selected'; else $selected = false; ?> 
                                <option value="{{$i+1}}" {{$selected}}>{{$i+1}}</option>
                            @endfor
                        </select>

                        @if( $errors->has('syst_interval') )
                            @foreach( $errors->get('syst_interval') as $error )
                                <span class="help-block">{{ $error }}</span>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    </div>
```

What we want to do is change the interval to the following options: every day (1), every week (7), every fortnight (14) and every month (28). 
What is the best way to go about this? I realise that it may not be possible without a significant overhaul of some of the code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your options are already based on numeric values, why not just write out the options?

```
<select name="syst_interval" id="syst_interval" class="form-control">
  <option value="0">Select value</option>
  <option<?php if($value == 1) echo ' selected="selected"' ?> value="1">Every day</option>
  <option<?php if($value == 7) echo ' selected="selected"' ?> value="7">Every week</option>
  <option<?php if($value == 14) echo ' selected="selected"' ?> value="14">Every fortnight</option>
  <option<?php if($value == 28) echo ' selected="selected"' ?> value="28">Every month</option>
</select>
```

The available options are hardcoded anyway, and the for loop is just for convenience, there's no need for anything fancy-pants dynamic stuff :)

And if you really hate to it that way, just defined an array and foreach over that, like:

```
<?php
   $options = array(0 => 'Choose a value', 1 => 'Every day', 7 => 'every Week', 14 => 'every fortnight', '28' => 'every month');
?>

<select name="syst_interval" id="syst_interval" class="form-control">

<?php
   foreach($options as $key => $text)
   {
     echo '<option value="' . $key . '"';
     print $key == $value ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
     echo '>' . $text . '</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: For some reason, I was expecting this to be more complicated. I hadn't thought about writing out the options...!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a "humanly-defined" intervals, you have to hard-code the options into the view thus:

```
<select name="syst_interval" id="syst_interval" class="form-control">
   <option value="0">Select value</option>
   <option value="1" <?= ( $value == 1 ) ?'selected':'' ?>  >Everyday</option>
   <option value="7" <?= ( $value == 7 ) ?'selected':'' ?>  >Every week</option>
   <option value="14" <?= ( $value == 14 ) ?'selected':'' ?>  >Every forthnight</option>
   <option value="28" <?= ( $value == 28) ?'selected':'' ?>  >Every month</option>
</select>
```